# How to get selected date and time from RadDatePicker

Tags: c#

How to get selected date and time from RadDatePicker (MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss)?

```
Response.Write(RadDatePicker1.SelectedDate.Value.ToString())

Response.Write(RadDatePicker1.SelectedDate.Value.ToString())
```

I got this

```
1/17/2019 12:00:00 AM
```

instead of this:

```
1/17/2019 12:23:45
```

Comment: Not sure but if I remember correctly there were two distinct controls. _RadDatePicker_ and __RadDateTimePicker__ It seems that you are using the wrong one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [check RadDateTimePicker value against current system date time value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30818851/check-raddatetimepicker-value-against-current-system-date-time-value)

Comment: Isn't RadDatePicker.SelectedDate a bog-standard `DateTime`? So, unless i am mistaken, your question essentially narrows down to how are `DateTime` values formatted as string, and how can the formatting be customized: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings

Answer (score 1):

// Get the current date from the Date picker

```
var date = RadDatePicker1.SelectedDate;
```

// Format the date as you need using any custom formatting rules

```
var formattedDate = date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt");
```

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30818851/check-raddatetimepicker-value-against-current-system-date-time-value?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

`RadDatePicker` in only get date you use a RadDateTimePicker

Markup:

```
<telerik:RadDateTimePicker x:Name="abc" Grid.Row="19" Grid.Column="1"></telerik:RadDateTimePicker>
```

Code

```
var selectedDate = abc.SelectedValue.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

[ToString after you choices date format than following this link](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/date-and-time-format-in-c-sharp-programming1)